# Node.js app when deployed on Azure throwing cannot find module error for my controller file

Tags: node.js, azure, http-status-code-500

I am new to Azure deployment and trying to deploy a simple Todo Node.js app on Azure.
Following is the structure of my Node app -

```
NodeToDo (Root folder)
   - app.js
   - controllers (sub folder)
       - todoController.js
```

In app.js file, I am using below code to set a reference to todoController.js file

```
var todoController = require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'controllers/todoController'));
```

When I deploy on Azure, and access the link it throws HTTP 500 error. 
The Log Stream in Azure Dashboard shows following log -
Cannot find module 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\controllers\todoController'

I already tried below things suggested at stackoverflow and other sites -

1. Tried changing the `require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'controllers/todoController'))` code to `require(path.resolve(__dirname, './controllers/todoController'))`
2. Tried changing the `require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'controllers/todoController'))` code to `require(path.resolve(__dirname, '/controllers/todoController'))`

Comment: can you check, if azure contains todo controller at `D:\home\site\wwwroot\controllers\todoController`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Max. I googled and found that we can view the folder structure of our deployed app on Kudu in Azure dashboard. So, I checked that and I cannot find my controller folder and todoController.js file there. Is there something I missed during deployment to deploy my sub-folder.

Comment: Well, I don't know how you deployed your app. Have you followed [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs)? *Push to Azure from Git* part

Comment: Thanks for your help Max. Somehow the sub-folder was not pushed to the remote Git URL that Azure provides. I tried it again after following the instructions in the link, and it worked.